# Android Studio : message "Configure project in Project Structure dialog"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I suddenly have the following message in my Android Studio window: "Configure project in Project Structure dialog"

[image]

What does that mean? What should I do to get rid of this message properly, without just clicking on 'Hide notification' ?

Note: my project compiles correctly. No visible problem due to this message.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When your dependencies are outdated or Android Studio detects that some of the libraries you're using have a new version released, it prompts you to open the Project Structure dialog (also found under *File -> Project Structure*) from where you can automatically update them to use the latest versions.

You don't have to do it if you don't want to, or if you know that some of those libraries introduce breaking changes for which you still don't cater, hence the "Hide Notification" option.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that In Android Studio they are recommending to make project in configuration changes using the "Project Structure" dialog (instead making changes directly in the project file) is a tool that allows you to configure various settings for your Android project. You can use it to manage dependencies, set up modules, configure build variants, and more.